# 403 forbidden when posting to a url

Tags: c#, post, http-status-code-403

I am posting a request to a website:

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.footlocker.dk/api/users/carts/current/entries?timestamp=1611595223668");

request.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
  string json = "{\"user\":\"test\"," + "\"password\":\"bla\"}";

  streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
  {
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
```

When I submit this request, I am getting a 403 forbidden, with following html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>footlocker.dk</title>
    <style>
      #cmsg{animation: A 1.5s;}@keyframes A{0%{opacity:0;}99%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0">
    <p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p>
    <script>
      var dd={'cid':'AHrlqAAAAAMA2k9UvgFgVkIAk04eSQ==','hsh':'A55FBF4311ED6F1BF9911EB71931D5','t':'fe','r':'b','s':17434,'host':'geo.captcha-delivery.com'}</script><script src="https://ct.captcha-delivery.com/c.js">
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Are there anyway I can make the browser think that JS is enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you trying to make this request? As per the [Footlocker Terms of Service](https://help.footlocker.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034292814),

> You may not without the prior written permission of Foot Locker, use any computer code, data mining software, "robot", "bot", "spider", "scraper" or other automatic device, or program, algorithm or methodology having similar processes or functionality, or any manual process, to monitor or copy any of the web pages, data or content found on this Site or App, or accessed through this Site or App.

I'm assuming you're attempting to perform unauthorized scraping/monitoring of this site, and I'd highly advise you stop as that's against the aforementioned terms and conditions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I have no intentions of exploiting this, and it's merely a proof of concept for me, and for educational use only, I would say.
However I respect your comment, and understand if you do not wish to help me.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to specify a user-agent.